# How can replace ipv4 answer for aaaa request in powerdns?

Tags: lua, dns, powerdns

I have an application which prefers sending ipv6 request  (AAAA) to our dns server, is it possible to replace ipv4 answer instead of v6?
I use powerdns recursor with authoritative backend.

Answer (score 0):

The original DNS protocol does not really allow this.  The DNS client will only process address records of the (single) type it asked for.

There is a protocol extension called [DNS64](https://tools.ietf.org/html/6147) and [PowerDNS supports DNS64](https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/dns64.html).